# Print glossary with divided sections for each group of words ordered by letter

Tags: formatting, glossaries

i successfully wrote my glossary and everything works great using this code

```
\usepackage[section]{glossaries}
    \makeglossaries
    \newglossaryentry{API}
    {
        name=API,
        text=API,
        description={acronimo per “Application Programming Interface”. Si tratta di procedure disponibili al programmatore utili all’espletamento di un certo compito all’interno di un programma. \pui{http://it.wikipedia.org/wiki/API}}
    }

...
\begin{document}
\glsaddall
\printglossary[style=altlist,title=Glossario]
\end{document}
```

Where instead of "..." there are all my \newglossarentry, about 100, which are words from "A" to "Z". Consider that in i want to have only the glossary in this document, so they are displayed all the words with their explanations. 
This is my actual sistuation in the image
[image: Actual situation: words ordered correctly by letter]

I would divide into sections each group of words and have a new page every time starts a letter in a new page. Something like in the following image
[image: Situation i want]

I have done that simply using

```
\begin{description}
        \item[Account] \hfill \\
        Indica........
\end{description}
```

But this is not what i want, i would continue to use the glossary syntax but personalize how the glossary is printed. Can someone help me? How can i customize my glossary in that sense?
Thank's in advance

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Something like this?

[image]

I've defined a new glossary style `myaltlistgroup` based on `altlistgroup`:

```
\newglossarystyle{myaltlistgroup}{%
  \setglossarystyle{altlistgroup}%
  \renewcommand*{\glsgroupheading}[1]{%
    \pagebreak%
    \item\makebox[\linewidth]{\Large\textbf{\glsgetgrouptitle{##1}}}%
    \vspace*{-\baselineskip}%
    \item\makebox[\linewidth]{\hspace*{3cm}\hrulefill\hspace*{3cm}}%
  }%
}
```

MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[section]{glossaries}

\newglossarystyle{myaltlistgroup}{%
  \setglossarystyle{altlistgroup}%
  \renewcommand*{\glsgroupheading}[1]{%
    \pagebreak%
    \item\makebox[\linewidth]{\Large\textbf{\glsgetgrouptitle{##1}}}%
    \vspace*{-\baselineskip}%
    \item\makebox[\linewidth]{\hspace*{3cm}\hrulefill\hspace*{3cm}}%
  }%
}

    \makeglossaries
    \newglossaryentry{API}
    {
        name=API,
        text=API,
        description={acronimo per “Application Programming Interface”. Si tratta di procedure disponibili al programmatore utili all’espletamento di un certo compito all’interno di un programma. {http://it.wikipedia.org/wiki/API}}
    }
    \newglossaryentry{BPI}
    {
        name=BPI,
        text=BPI,
        description={acronimo per “Application Programming Interface”. Si tratta di procedure disponibili al programmatore utili all’espletamento di un certo compito all’interno di un programma. {http://it.wikipedia.org/wiki/API}}
    }

\begin{document}
\glsaddall
\printglossary[style=myaltlistgroup,title=Glossario]
\end{document}
```

Comment: Yeah!It is really what i want! Thank's! Now i'm trying to personalize more that style to see different solutions.

Comment: @user2195977 You're welcome. Happy it helped!